# Where to find NSF Reports (For mathematical expository purpose)?

Tags: grants, advice, exposition

This is **not** asking about how to apply for funding.

I just find that some NSF funding report (near the end of the funding cycle) is quite interesting read. In particular, it's almost like a research report of the PI's several years' work. It provides some insight how the PI's different papers are related, and it's for the most part very accessible for non-experts.

Are these reports open to public and where to find them?

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting question.  While I hope it garners some answers here, I suspect that academia.stackexchange (or even a few web searches) will be more likely to answer this than this forum will.  Gerhard "Let's Wait And See Anyway" Paseman, 2013.02.19

Comment: Lewis Black starts at minute 38: http://www.c-spanvideo.org/program/186191-1  

Comment: @Teo. So you mean that they are not public data?

Comment: This is an interesting point: it is various publishers' stance that instead of making final articles open access if they are funded by public money, the reports (as mentioned here) should be made more prominent and/or publicly available. I hardly think that an NSF report is a substitute for an article with theorems and proofs...

Comment: ...but maybe a decent substitute for a survey without theorems and proofs.

That said, I am almost sure that the european equivalent of NSF reports are *not* public.

Comment: This question is in no way specific to mathematics. As such it is not on-topic here. Gerhard Paseman mentioned the appropriate site. (Except if it should ask also for individual postings of such reports, but first it does not seem like this and sencond this would not be a good question either.) Voted to close

Comment: OK, I am asking a follow up question on academia.stackexchange.
Here: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/8111/foia-request-for-full-nsf-awards-proposal-and-report